# Ajustar css somente de um td

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho um `table`:

```
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="imgpadrao" src="xxxxx" alt=""></td>
            <td> Recebido </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tenho muitas tabelas assim e preciso alterar só o o primeiro `td` colocando um estilo pra ele (`width: 50px`), o que tem a class `imgpadrao` sem afetar o outro `td`. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o *pseudo-selector* `first-child` que irá aplicar para todos os primeiros:

```css
tr td:first-child {
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="imgpadrao" src="xxxxx" alt="">Primeiro</td>
      <td> Recebido </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Outra TD</td>
      <td> Recebido </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show, obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar `:first-child` para pegar o primeiro elemento dentro do `tr`

```css
td:first-child > img {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="imgpadrao" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnyxp.jpg?s=32&g=1" alt=""></td>
        <td> Recebido </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir um class para seu td.

```
  <td class="exemplo"><img class="imgpadrao" src="xxxxx" alt=""></td>
```

E no css colocar o width nele.

```
  .exemplo{
     width: 50px;
  }
```

Ou você coloca o style dentro de sua tag, ficando assim:

```
  <td style="width: 50px;"><img class="imgpadrao" src="xxxxx" alt=""></td>
```

Comment: Eu esqueci de falar mas não queria criar class :).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar seletores do CSS para fazer isso. Dois exemplos de como fazer isso é:

```
td:nth-child(1){
    width: 50px;
}
```

ou então:

```
td:first-child{
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Eu esqueci de falar mas não queria criar class :).